# PHP for-loop with HTML inside not functioning properly

Tags: html, php, image

So, I'm trying to build a slideshow for a site I'm making, but it's unclear how many images I am going to have to include. The current code for retrieving the images is included below, but when run it is only displaying:

[image: output from code]

```
<?php
                $dir = dirname(__FILE__).'/img';
                $images = scandir($dir);
                if($images)
                {
                    foreach($images as $image)
                    {?>
                        <div class="slide active-slide slide-feature">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <a href="#"><img src= <?php echo ('"' . $dir . '/' . $image . '"') ?> ></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Note: When I just type out the HTML by hand and include specific URLs, the HTML itself works fine, so I'm assuming it's an issue with the integration of HTML and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> `$dir = dirname(__FILE__).'/img';`

In this context, `$dir` is an absolute *filesystem* path, not a URL. So, when you use `$dir` in the `src` attribute of the `img` element, the image is never going to be found. You could probably fix this by simply making the URL relative (although a root-relative URL would be preferable), for example:

```
<a href="#"><img src="img/<?=$image?>"></a>
```

You should also note that the `scandir()` function will also return the two "special" directories `.` and `..`, so these will need to be skipped at the start of your `foreach()` loop. For example:

```
if (in_array($image,array('.','..'))) continue;
```

Mixing *output* inside PHP constructs in this way (by breaking in/out of PHP mode) is not good practice as it restricts portability, harder to read, harder to debug etc. Instead, consider assigning your output to a variable and echo'ing this at the end of your script.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. Follow up question:
My slideshow is now functioning for the most part, but my Javascript that was functional with a previously declared number of images (without the PHP) is no longer completely functional. It's setup so that when it is on the last item and you hit the next arrow, it goes back to the first one. The slideshow can be found [here](http://www.zacharyamason.com/slideshow.php) and the JS can be found [here](http://www.zacharyamason.com/js/slideshow-app.js)